# Plotting real time data with PyQt

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt4

So I'm trying to plot real time data with PyQt. I have it working in a sense, but matplotlib seems to be slowing it down a lot. If I reduce the number of plots I can get the sample rate I want. I have two timer events, one that gathers data and another that plots, with a ratio of 10 to 1.

Searching for a fix I found about Blitting with Matplotlib from SO, and was led to tutorials like [this](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/). The problem I'm seeing is that this is only dealing with the plotting part. Every attempt I have made at sampling and plotting a portion of the data I've gathered ends in a crash.

So an outline of what I'd like to do would be this

```
class graph(ParentMplCanvas):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
      self.x    = range(1000)
      self.data = np.zeros(1000)
      #set timer for data to be sampled once every 10ms.
      self.updateData()
      self.line, = self.ax.plot(self.x,self.data, animated=True)
      # Update the plot every second
      self.gTimer = fig.canvas.new_timer(interval=1000)
      self.gTimer.add_callback(self.update_figure)
      self.gtimer.start()

   def updateData(self):
      self.i += 1
      #append with 0's if self.i > 1000
      self.data[self.i] = self.funcToGrabCurrentValFromDevice()
      self.updateTimer()
   def updateTimer(self):
      self.dTimer = Timer(0.01,updateData)
      self.dTimer.start()

class ApplicationWindow(gui.QMainWindow):
   some stuff to call docked windows and the above graph in a docked window see [how I did it here][2]
```

Maybe I am just not understanding the blitting, but everything I'm seeing there they already have all the data. Any time I've tried to just access a portion of the data it seems to crash the program. I'm trying to just plot a 100 sample region at a time and have it continuously update.

**Where I am lost**:

How do I properly write `update_figure` so that I can plot the last 100 (or n) data points that were sampled?

Comment: On the one hand you're saying that the program is working, but that it's slow. On the other hand you're saying it crashes. Since in the code you show, there is no blitting applied, I'm not sure what exactly you expect as an answer here.

Comment: The program is slow in the when I am not using the blitting. When I add the blitting it crashes. What I'm asking is how do I write `update_figure` with blitting. The problem is without blitting I am getting 1 frame every second. So I'm looking for a way to up the speed. If I reduce the number of plots I get the correct speed.

Comment: Is the `Timer` you use a pyqt `QTimer`? If so, don't you create a huge amount of different timers (one new Timer for every data update) and couldn't that be the reason for the crashing?

Comment: I'm working with a device that has multiple inputs. One timer is called to update the data at the specified sample rate. The other is used to update the graph. If I plot only 2 of the data lines I'm getting the speed I want. If I plot 8 I get really slow performance. That's what has led me to believe that it is matplotlib causing the slowdown.

Comment: As for writing with the blitting, I'm completely lost on that. I'm currently reading some of your other posts.

Comment: My point about the timer is that I'm not sure if a timer that looses its reference will actually stop itself. If not, you will have 100 timers after 100 iterations of the animation, which may slow things down. Concerning blitting, the easiest way is to use a `FuncAnimation` and turn `blit=True`. But since I don't know where the problem lies it's hard to tell how you should write the function; there are many possible ways and also a lot of questions and answers around.